# How to print out a list of tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

This is my code:

```
def points_per_game(master_list):
container1= []
for line in master_list:
    container1.append((float(line[18]),line[0],line[2]))
container1.sort(reverse=True)
container1 = container1[:10]
return container1
```

And the output of my code is a list of tuples:

```
[(1.92, 'Wayne Gretzky', 'C'), (1.88, 'Mario Lemieux', 'C'), (1.5, 'Mike Bossy', 'R'), (1.4, 'Joe Malone', 'C'), (1.39, 'Bobby Orr', 'D'), (1.33, 'Connor McDavid', 'C'), (1.31, 'Marcel Dionne', 'C'), (1.28, 'Sidney Crosby', 'C'), (1.27, 'Peter Stastny', 'C'), (1.25, 'Peter Forsberg', 'C')]
```

How to turn the list into the picture below, changing the order of the floating point number, the name, and the letter, with format `"{:<20s}{:>8s}{:>16s}"` in main()?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the list elements and format it. You can use tuple unpacking to reorder the elements.

```
for score, player, letter in points_per_game(master_list):
    print("{:<20s}{:>8s}{:>16.2f}".format(player, letter, score))
```

You need to use `f` formatting for the `float` scores, and you can use `.2` to specify 2 digits after the decimal.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the format in a function and print using `map` (no loop alternative)

```
formatter = lambda tup: "{:<20s}{:>8s}{:>16s}".format(*map(str, tup))
print('\n'.join(map(formatter, your_tuple_list)))
```